# How to use BeanShell server to modify Jmeter's user properties while running the test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I would like to control throughput in real-time while running the test.
How do I do that using BeanShell server?

Basically I want to update a user property 'throughput' (used in Constant Throughput Timer) from command line while the test is running.

**Solution:**
Based on Dmitri's answer I did the following:
1. I added to `user.properties`:

```
beanshell.server.port=9000  
beanshell.server.file=beanshell.server.file=/home/sam/JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0/extras/startup.bsh
```

2. Started JMeter and my test.
3. Executed this command in Terminal:
   `~/JMeter/apache-jmeter-4.0$ java -jar lib/bshclient.jar localhost 9000 /home/sam/JMeter/beanshell/setthroughput.bsh 100`
4. Value of `throughput` property is now 100. Fantastic!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   beanshell.server.port=9000
   beanshell.server.file=../extras/startup.bsh
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the settings up
3. Set `throughput` property in the Constant Throughput Timer using __P() function like:

   ```
   ${__P(throughput,60)}
   ```

   this will set default throughput to 60 requests per minute (1 request per second), if `throughput` property will be defined somewhere somehow - the value will get overriden.
4. Create `setthroughput.bsh` in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation with the following contents:

   ```
   setprop("throughput", args[0]);
   ```
5. In the runtime you will be able to modify the throughput like:

   ```
   java -jar bshclient.jar localhost 9000 setthroughput.bsh 100
   ```

   [image: JMeter set throughput]

More information: [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)

---

I believe it would be easier if you switch to [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which has [`load_profile` property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) so you will be able to control throughput in more flexible and efficient manner. You can install Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thank you. Great answer!

Comment: @Dmitri, I get "command not found: setprop... when I run it. Any idea?